# I am using one edittext which is blank already for that i want to know some listener

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a blank/empty edittext i want to know the "backspace listener" or "count zero listener" for now am using addTextChangedListener() but none of the method is getting executed when am pressing backSpace key because that is already empty.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)
        Field2.setText("");
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {                 
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
           if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
             //on backspace
             }
    return false        
        }
});
```